# Error specifying font-family with webpack and sass

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I'm trying to specify a font-family variable in my sass file and it's giving me grief. Here's the sass definition:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

What's strange is that if I remove the quotes from `Lato` and `Helvetica Neue` it compiles just fine. If I don't I get this error message:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/sass-loader?
outputStyle=comporessed&includePaths[]=
/Users/micah/trackr/app/app/assets/bower_components
&includePaths[]=/Users/micah/trackr/app/app/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets&includePaths[]
=/Users/micah/trackr/app/node_modules!./app/assets/stylesheets/landing.scss
    File to import not found or unreadable: Lato
```

**Update**

What's more strange is that even though an error is generated, the file is actually compiled and the css is there.

Comment: what if you change double quotes to single quote?

Comment: Same issue unfortunately :/

Comment: For what it's worth, it compiles just fine using vanilla Sass.